# local host api access from Android device

Tags: android, api, android-studio

I have created an API in C#, Visual studio and it is running on my `localhost` with address `http://localhost:xxxxx/api/allproduct`.

I have also created an Android app in Android Studio and tried to access the above API. I am debugging my app using data cable (Not by emulator). I am not able to access the API.

I used `chrome://inspect/#devices` and with the help of port forwarding I am able to access api in my mobile's browser. But when I am trying to connect this API through code (app code in Android studio), it is telling "could not connect to `http://localhost:xxxxx/api/allproduct`".

Any one Please suggest any alternate.

Comment: Replace localhost with ip address

Comment: Please use with your IP Address

Comment: Good Question! 1 up for u!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you everyone for suggestions.
I used you ideas and added some more. I ran my api with IP and used chrome://inspect/#devices for port forwarding and after that I opened this api in my mobile browser(USB cable connected). After that I started to debug my android application which was using the api. it ran successfully.

Point I noted that when api was not running in my mobiles browser, my android application was crashing and when api was running, app was not crashing.

I was accessing api in my mobiles browser by localhost:xxxx/api/product

Comment: Thankyou soo much! i was searching for this type of help. Its really worth :) 1 plus for you!

Comment: Thank you. "chrome://inspect/#devices" I didn't know this. This is genius.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, `localhost` is *"this machine."

In other words, "to your Android, it's your Android!"

Your phone is talking to *itself,* not to the machine that's running your API.  You must provide (or, enable the phone to locate ...) the IP-address of *that* machine.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a network in which your device and server are in same network. like you can connect laptop and mobile with wifi or hotspots.

then use ip address of network(mobile hotspots or wifi ip address).

replace localhost to ip address and access the API.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not an answer, it is a comment instead. A good answer does not need to be clarified, but yours needs it instead. Enhance it, please.

Answer (score 0):

replace ip addess with the localhost. make sure computer and mobile device is connected to the same network and you use the computer ip address (api hosted computer).
ex: `http://192.168.1.1:xxxx/api/allproduct`